# django-allauth AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS is not working

Tags: django, django-allauth

the redirect from `/login/` when user is authenticated is handled in this method:

```py
class RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated and app_settings.AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS:
            redirect_to = self.get_authenticated_redirect_url()
            response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
            return _ajax_response(request, response)
        else:
            response = super(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, self).dispatch(
                request, *args, **kwargs
            )
        return response

    def get_authenticated_redirect_url(self):
        redirect_field_name = self.redirect_field_name
        return get_login_redirect_url(
            self.request,
            url=self.get_success_url(),
            redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name,
        )
```

the AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS  is set by default to True according to [documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)
using breakpoints to debug, I have found out that `request.user.is_authenticated and app_settings.AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS` is always returning false, changing the condition to `request.user.is_authenticated and settings.AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS`
the condition was corrected and it returns True
and the user was redirected from `/login/` URL to the one set in settings: `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"`

my question why the app_settings was not able to fetch the variables in settings?
and How do I fix this problem?

Comment: What was the settings variable?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS, this is the variable, and by default, it is set to True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that the *Django settings variable* is ***`ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS`***, not  *`AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS`* (Ref the [doc](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html))

So, you should set the value for `ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS` in your `settings.py`